# Adjusted seams in UV, is it possible to mirror them on a symmetrical object?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I have a model that is symmetrical (a mattress). On one side, I have adjusted the seams in the UV editor to match the texture correctly.

[image]

I would like to have the same adjustments I made on the seams on the other part of the mattress. Is it possible?

[image]

Image 2 should become like Image 1.

I have uploaded the .blend file

[image]